# Adding Facebook login credentials

Tags: support, openid, login, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

I've been using OpenID to log in since stackoverflow was created.  Now, I'd like to associate my facebook credentials with my account.  How do I do this?

When I clicked on facebook to log in to stackoverflow, hoping to add my openID, it created a whole new stackoverflow account for me.  help.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a subcase of [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste) The short answer is that you should set both accounts to use the same e-mail address and flag any of your posts for mod attention with a short description.

Comment: I can't get back to my old OpenID account.  Now it just automatically sends me to the new Facebook account.  My old OpenID stackoverflow account I had had for over 2 years.

Comment: And when I try and set the new facebook credentials to the same email as my old OpenID, it won't let me - saying that email is already registered.